# How to add CSS classes to a lightning:overlayLibrary that is already open?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-overlaylibrary

I am using a lightning:overlaylibrary component to display a modal dialog where a user can perform different actions.
Based on the user's interaction and the data he provides, a follow up form appears in the modal dialog. This is all working just fine, but I would like to apply a specific CSS class to the modal dialog when the user arrives at that follow-up form to increase the modals size.

The modal should only get larger, when that particular form is displayed, otherwise the default size is good.

I am currently opening my modal dialog like this:

```
$A.createComponents([
        ["c:MyModalContent", {
                'dateFrom' : dateFrom,
                'dateTo' : dateTo
            }]
        ],
       function(content, status) {
           if (status === "SUCCESS") {  
               component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({
                   header: "Add service",
                   body: content[0], 
                   showCloseButton: true,
                   // Note: During opening the modal, i do NOT want this class applied. Upon some interaction in "c:MyModalContent" it should get applied.
                   //cssClass: "slds-modal_large"
               });
           }                               
       });
```

Within my "c:MyModalContent" component, I've tried:

```
    $A.util.addClass(component.find('overlayLib'), 'slds-modal_large');
```

but that does not do anything.
I am able to interact with the modal from my component however, e.g. to close it:

```
component.find('overlayLib').notifyClose();
```

When I used Chrome's Dev Tools and inspect the DOM and manually add that class to the `<div>` that would have contained it, if I would have specified it during opening, the resizing works just fine. So it's "just" a matter of how to achieve it in the JS...

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks